# ROS class method callback error

Tags: c++, class, static, ros, pointer-to-member

I am banging my head on this 1 error. I have made 3 files out of which 1 is a main.cpp, 2nd is a .cpp file and the 3rd is a .hpp code file.
For some reason the subscriber callback function is giving me an error when I am trying to call it from a class method. The code is as follows:

File 1: main.cpp

```
#include "ControlTurtlebot.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

//initialize the ROS node
ros::init(argc, argv, "free_space_navigation_node");
ros::NodeHandle n;

ControlTurtlebot obj;

//subscribe to the odometry topic to get the position of the robot
obj.pose_subscriber = n.subscribe("/odom", 10, &ControlTurtlebot::poseCallback, &obj);
//register the velocity publisher
obj.pub =n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("mobile_base/commands/velocity", 1000);

ros::spinOnce();
ros::Rate loop(1);
loop.sleep();loop.sleep();loop.sleep();//loop.sleep();loop.sleep();
ros::spinOnce();

while (ros::ok()){
    ros::spinOnce();loop.sleep();
    printf("robot initial pose: (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f)\n", obj.turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.x, obj.turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.y, obj.radian2degree(tf::getYaw(obj.turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.orientation)));

    double velocity = 0.3;

    obj.moveShape(1.0, 3, 120, velocity);

    //exercise: try to remove the ros::SpinOnce() and observe and comment the result
    ros::spinOnce();loop.sleep();ros::spinOnce();
    printf("robot final pose: (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f)\n", obj.turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.x, obj.turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.y, obj.radian2degree(tf::getYaw(obj.turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.orientation)));
    return 0;
}

return 0;
```

}

And the other file is:

File 2: ControlTurtlebot.hpp

```
#pragma once

#ifndef INCLUDE_CONTROLTURTLEBOT_HPP_
#define INCLUDE_CONTROLTURTLEBOT_HPP_

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"
#include "tf/tf.h"
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <fstream>

class ControlTurtlebot {


  public:

  #define ANGULAR_VELOCITY_MINIMUM_THRESHOLD 0.4
  #define pi 22/7

  //declare publishers
  ros::Publisher pub;
  //declare subscribers
  ros::Subscriber pose_subscriber;
  //global variable to update the position of the robot
  nav_msgs::Odometry turtlebot_odom_pose;

  ros::NodeHandle n;


  //callback function for the /odom topic to update the pose
  void poseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& pose_message);



  //the function that makes the robot moves forward and backward
  void move_linear(double speed, double distance, bool isForward);

  //the function that makes the robot rotates left and right
  double rotate(double ang_vel, double angle_radian, bool isClockwise);

  double degree2radian(double degreeAngle);
  double radian2degree(double radianAngle);

  void moveShape(double sideLength, double totalSides, double angle, double velocity);

};

#endif
```

`
And the last file is:

File 3: ControlTurtlebot.cpp

```
#include "ControlTurtlebot.hpp"



void ControlTurtlebot::poseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& pose_message){

turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.x=pose_message->pose.pose.position.x;
turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.y=pose_message->pose.pose.position.y;
turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.z=pose_message->pose.pose.position.z;

turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.orientation.w=pose_message->pose.pose.orientation.w;
turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.orientation.x=pose_message->pose.pose.orientation.x;
turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.orientation.y=pose_message->pose.pose.orientation.y;
turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.orientation.z=pose_message->pose.pose.orientation.z;

}



void ControlTurtlebot::moveShape(double sideLength, double totalSides, double angle, double velocity){
    for (int i=0;i<totalSides;i++){
        move_linear(velocity, sideLength, true);
        rotate (velocity, degree2radian(angle), true);
    }   
}


void ControlTurtlebot::move_linear(double speed, double distance, bool isForward){
    //delcare a Twist message to send velocity commands
    geometry_msgs::Twist VelocityMessage;
    //initial pose of the turtlebot before start moving
    nav_msgs::Odometry initial_turtlebot_odom_pose;

    //set the linear velocity to a positive value if isFoward is true
    if (isForward)
        VelocityMessage.linear.x =abs(speed);
    //all velocities of other axes must be zero.
    VelocityMessage.linear.y = VelocityMessage.linear.z =VelocityMessage.angular.x =VelocityMessage.angular.y =VelocityMessage.angular.z =0;

    double distance_moved = 0.0;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10); // we publish the velocity at 10 Hz (10 times a second)

    //we update the initial_turtlebot_odom_pose using the turtlebot_odom_pose global variable updated in the callback function poseCallback
    initial_turtlebot_odom_pose = turtlebot_odom_pose;

    do{
        pub.publish(VelocityMessage);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
        distance_moved = sqrt(pow((turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.x-initial_turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.x), 2) +
            pow((turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.y-initial_turtlebot_odom_pose.pose.pose.position.y), 2));

    }while((distance_moved<distance)&&(ros::ok()));
//finally, stop the robot when the distance is moved
    VelocityMessage.linear.x =0;
    pub.publish(VelocityMessage);
}



double ControlTurtlebot::rotate(double angular_velocity, double radians,  bool clockwise)
{

//delcare a Twist message to send velocity commands
geometry_msgs::Twist VelocityMessage;
//declare tf transform listener: this transform listener will be used to listen and capture the transformation between
// the odom frame (that represent the reference frame) and the base_footprint frame the represent moving frame
tf::TransformListener TFListener;
//declare tf transform
//init_transform: is the transformation before starting the motion
tf::StampedTransform init_transform;
//current_transformation: is the transformation while the robot is moving
tf::StampedTransform current_transform;
//initial coordinates (for method 3)
nav_msgs::Odometry initial_turtlebot_odom_pose;

double angle_turned =0.0;

//validate angular velocity; ANGULAR_VELOCITY_MINIMUM_THRESHOLD is the minimum allowed
angular_velocity=((angular_velocity>ANGULAR_VELOCITY_MINIMUM_THRESHOLD)?angular_velocity:ANGULAR_VELOCITY_MINIMUM_THRESHOLD);

while(radians < 0) radians += 2*pi;
while(radians > 2*pi) radians -= 2*pi;

//wait for the listener to get the first message
TFListener.waitForTransform("base_footprint", "odom", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(1.0));

//record the starting transform from the odometry to the base frame
TFListener.lookupTransform("base_footprint", "odom", ros::Time(0), init_transform);

//the command will be to turn at 0.75 rad/s
VelocityMessage.linear.x = VelocityMessage.linear.y = 0.0;
VelocityMessage.angular.z = angular_velocity;
if (clockwise) VelocityMessage.angular.z = -VelocityMessage.angular.z;

//the axis we want to be rotating by
tf::Vector3 desired_turn_axis(0,0,1);
if (!clockwise) desired_turn_axis = -desired_turn_axis;

ros::Rate rate(10.0);
bool done = false;
while (!done )
{
    //send the drive command
    pub.publish(VelocityMessage);
    rate.sleep();
    //get the current transform
    try
    {
        TFListener.waitForTransform("base_footprint", "odom", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(1.0));
        TFListener.lookupTransform("base_footprint", "odom", ros::Time(0), current_transform);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
        break;
    }
    tf::Transform relative_transform = init_transform.inverse() * current_transform;
    tf::Vector3 actual_turn_axis = relative_transform.getRotation().getAxis();
    angle_turned = relative_transform.getRotation().getAngle();

    if (fabs(angle_turned) < 1.0e-2) continue;
    if (actual_turn_axis.dot(desired_turn_axis ) < 0 )
        angle_turned = 2 * pi - angle_turned;

    if (!clockwise)
        VelocityMessage.angular.z = (angular_velocity-ANGULAR_VELOCITY_MINIMUM_THRESHOLD) * (fabs(radian2degree(radians-angle_turned)/radian2degree(radians)))+ANGULAR_VELOCITY_MINIMUM_THRESHOLD;
    else
        if (clockwise)
            VelocityMessage.angular.z = (-angular_velocity+ANGULAR_VELOCITY_MINIMUM_THRESHOLD) * (fabs(radian2degree(radians-angle_turned)/radian2degree(radians)))-ANGULAR_VELOCITY_MINIMUM_THRESHOLD;

    if (angle_turned > radians) {
        done = true;
        VelocityMessage.linear.x = VelocityMessage.linear.y = VelocityMessage.angular.z = 0;
        pub.publish(VelocityMessage);
    }

}
if (done) return angle_turned;
return angle_turned;
}

/* makes conversion from radian to degree */
double ControlTurtlebot::radian2degree(double radianAngle){
return (radianAngle*57.2957795);
}


/* makes conversion from degree to radian */
double ControlTurtlebot::degree2radian(double degreeAngle){
    return (degreeAngle/57.2957795);
}
```

And the error that I get on using the above mentioned subscriber callback in main.cpp file is:

> CMakeFiles/free_space_navigation_node.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function
>   `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x400): undefined reference to`
>   ControlTurtlebot::poseCallback(boost::shared_ptr
>
> > const> const&)' main.cpp:(.text+0x5f0): undefined reference to `ControlTurtlebot::radian2degree(double)' main.cpp:(.text+0x674):
> >     undefined reference to`ControlTurtlebot::moveShape(double, double,
> >     double, double)' main.cpp:(.text+0x6b1): undefined reference to
> >     `ControlTurtlebot::radian2degree(double)' collect2: error: ld returned
> >     1 exit status
> >     toy_robot/CMakeFiles/free_space_navigation_node.dir/build.make:118:
> >     recipe for target
> >     '/home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/toy_robot/free_space_navigation_node'
> >     failed make[2]: ***
> >     [/home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/toy_robot/free_space_navigation_node]
> >     Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2938: recipe for target
> >     'toy_robot/CMakeFiles/free_space_navigation_node.dir/all' failed
> >     make[1]: *** [toy_robot/CMakeFiles/free_space_navigation_node.dir/all]
> >     Error 2 Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all]
> >     Error 2

And if I change the subscribe callback line in main.cpp from:

```
    obj.pose_subscriber = n.subscribe("/odom", 10, &ControlTurtlebot::poseCallback, &obj);
```

to

```
    obj.pose_subscriber = n.subscribe("/odom", 10, ControlTurtlebot::poseCallback);
```

So I get an error as follows:

> error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void
>   ControlTurtlebot::poseCallback(const ConstPtr&)’
>       obj.pose_subscriber = n.subscribe("/odom", 10, ControlTurtlebot::poseCallbac
>                                                                        ^ toy_robot/CMakeFiles/free_space_navigation_node.dir/build.make:62:
>   recipe for target
>   'toy_robot/CMakeFiles/free_space_navigation_node.dir/src/main.cpp.o'
>   failed make[2]: ***
>   [toy_robot/CMakeFiles/free_space_navigation_node.dir/src/main.cpp.o]
>   Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2938: recipe for target
>   'toy_robot/CMakeFiles/free_space_navigation_node.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]: *** [toy_robot/CMakeFiles/free_space_navigation_node.dir/all]
>   Error 2 Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all]
>   Error 2

I don't understand what is the problem. I have also tried changing the callfunction definition from void to static void callback(), but it again reverts to the 1st error, similar to when I am using the above-mentioned subscriber method.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you build ControlTurtlebot.cpp together with main.cpp in the CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: Seconding @IsakT. -- please update your question to include your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Hello @Isak T., I got the solution to the problem. The problem was that just added the main.cpp in the CMakeLists.txt but not the other file, i.e., ControlTurtlebot.cpp. Because of this, it was showing me this error. Thank you so much still!